# How to install Ganache UI on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: ganache

Tried downloading the amd64 Debian release: https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-ui/releases/download/v2.5.4/ganache-2.5.4-linux-x86_64.AppImage

`wget https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-ui/releases/download/v2.5.4/ganache-2.5.4-linux-x86_64.AppImage`

`chmod a+x ganache-2.5.4-linux-x86_64.AppImage`

`./ganache-2.5.4-linux-x86_64.AppImage`

It won't initialize. I get back an error message:

`/tmp/.mount_ganach7FhmyY/Ganache: error while loading shared libraries: libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

tried `sudo apt-get install libgdk_pixbuf`, Linux can't find the package

so I found this instead: https://packages.debian.org/cgi-bin/search_contents.pl?word=libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0&searchmode=searchfiles&case=insensitive&version=unstable&arch=i386

tried to download it via `wget` and initializing with `./` but nothing's working

also tried downloading the latest repo of https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-ui

ran `nvm use 12.13.1`

`npm install`

`npm run dev`

Only to get an error message stating that `Electron-webpack` is missing or something.

UPDATE: tried "yarn install", "yarn start"; received this error message

`/home/ubuntu/ganache-ui/node_modules/electron/dist/electron: error while loading shared libraries: libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: For the missing library, execute the following:
`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev` or the following: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgtk2.0-0`

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following commands to have ganache up and running:

```
$ apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget libgtk-3-dev libfuse-dev libgtkextra-dev libgconf2-dev libnss3 libasound2 libxtst-dev libxss1 libx11-6 libx11-xcb-dev
$ wget https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-ui/releases/download/v2.5.4/ganache-2.5.4-linux-x86_64.AppImage
$ chmod +x ganache-2.5.4-linux-x86_64.AppImage 
$ ./ganache-2.5.4-linux-x86_64.AppImage
```

Comment: Followed that to a T, got:

`/tmp/.mount_ganachIQ0UHV/Ganache: error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-3.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: Actually ran `sudo apt-get install libgtk-3.so.0` and now I'm getting `(Ganache:9526): Gtk-WARNING **: 20:49:49.527: cannot open display:`

Comment: `libgtk` should also come with the dependencies I shared... Which ubuntu version are you running this on ?
Also, please include the whole error message for the display.

Comment: Also, maybe try double clicking on the `AppImage` file, might work

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this error

```
    Gtk-WARNING **: 22:55:49.527: cannot open display:
```

Add the following to /etc/sudoers

```
    Defaults env_keep=DISPLAY
```

Than restart your terminal and you should be able to use it from your normal user, don't launch it with the root user using su. Launch it from the regular master account.